# param of asio timer async_wait difference lambda, bind, function pointer

Tags: c++, c++11, boost, c++14, asio

When I use `boost::asio::steady_timer`, I find something difference between `lambda`, `bind`, `function pointer`.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/asio.hpp>

void print() { std::cout << "Hello, world!" << std::endl; }

int main()
{
    boost::asio::io_context io;

    boost::asio::steady_timer t(io, boost::asio::chrono::seconds(5));
    t.async_wait(&print); // Error
    t.async_wait([]{print();}) // Error
    t.async_wait(std::bind(print)); // Done

    io.run();

    return 0;
}
```

I read asio manual, async_wait handler need `const boost::system::error_code& error` param. So if I changed `print` to `void print(const boost::system::error_code & /*e*/)`, all things was right. But asio example of `timer4/timer.cc` && `timeouts/server.cc` used handler creating by bind without `void print(const boost::system::error_code & /*e*/)`. When I changed to lambda, compile was wrong. So, what difference of signature been had between bind && lambda.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <boost/bind.hpp>

class printer
{
public:
    printer(boost::asio::io_context &io)
        : timer_(io, boost::asio::chrono::seconds(1)), count_(0)
    {
        timer_.async_wait(std::bind(&printer::print, this));
    }

    ~printer() { std::cout << "Final count is " << count_ << std::endl; }

    void print()
    {
        if (count_ < 5) {
            std::cout << count_ << std::endl;
            ++count_;

            timer_.expires_at(timer_.expiry() +
                      boost::asio::chrono::seconds(1));
            timer_.async_wait(boost::bind(&printer::print, this));
            // timer_.async_wait([this]{print();}); Error
        }
    }

private:
    boost::asio::steady_timer timer_;
    int count_;
};

int main()
{
    boost::asio::io_context io;
    printer p(io);
    io.run();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I has found the answer, bind will ignore the overmuch param。Such as `void print() { cout << 1 << endl; } int main() { auto f = bind(print); f(2); }` is right.

Answer (score 0):

The "partial" generated by `std::bind` detects and ignores arguments provided by the invocation point and not explicitly wired to the bound code.

A minimalistic example ([godbolted](https://godbolt.org/z/t9hqmK)):

```
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>

void callme(std::function<void(int, float)> arg) {
    arg(42, 4.2);
}

// or like this
// template <typename F> void callme(F&& arg) {
//     arg(42, 4.2);
// }

int main()
{
    auto fn = std::bind([](){std::cout << "hi there" << std::endl; });
    // auto fn = std::bind([](auto&& x){std::cout << "x=" << x << std::endl; }, std::placeholders::_1);  <-- this works too and prints 42
    // auto fn = std::bind([](auto&& x){std::cout << "x=" << x << std::endl; }, std::placeholders::_2);  <-- and works too and prints 4.2

    callme(fn);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I read the asio code, found that `BOOST_ASIO_WAIT_HANDLER_CHECK(WaitHandler, handler) type_check;`. This did't work, how can check that did bind match all params and ignored nothing.

Comment: After viewed your code, I had a question, that `function <void()>` can be convert to `function <void (int, float)>` without any compiler error.

Comment: @Anien - it's not converted, bind is generating exactly the required signature, in example with a single bound arg it would be `std::function<void(int, float)>([](int a1, float a2) { bound_callback(a1); });`

Comment: I didn't agree with that. I find the type of fn is `std::__1::__bind<main::$_0&>`, the type of lambda is `main::$_0`. So compiler convert it to `std::function <void (int, float)> `. I need to read the functor implemention :).

Comment: @Anien I admire your stubbornness! Please post your findings, am very curious as well.

Comment: @Anien yes wrapping in a strong typed wrapper **will** work to validate the signature. However it **also** erases the handler type, which is _bad_ in the design of ASIO (e.g. if the handler was wrapped by a strand, that information is erased, and that may break any composed operations/custom handler dispatch)

Comment: @bobah, I read the llvm-5 functor implemetion code today. I found that function ctor `template <class _Rp, class... _ArgTypes> template <class _Fp, class> function<_Rp(_ArgTypes...)>::function(_Fp __f) ` use callable `static const bool value = is_same<void, _Rp>::value || is_convertible<typename __invoke_of<_Fp&, _ArgTypes...>::type, _Rp>::value;` for guard.

Comment: @bobah,  In llvm, `__invoke_of` is the base class of `invoke_result`. By clang, `std::bind([](){std::cout << "hi there" << std::endl; });` can be called with `(int, float)`, becasue bind ignore overmuch params. So `std::bind([](){std::cout << "hi there" << std::endl; });` can be converted to `std::function<void(int, float)>`. It only check arg, not return_result. So `function<void(int)> a = bind(function<string()>());` is right. But running caused `std::__1::bad_function_call: std::exception`. This is a problem. We need to check this code strongly by ourselves.

Comment: @bobah @sehe, `template <class _Fp, class... _BoundArgs> class bind` use `typedef typename __make_tuple_indices<sizeof...(_BoundArgs)>::type __indices;`. When called `operator()`, finally called `return _VSTD::__apply_functor(__f_, __bound_args_, __indices(), tuple<_Args &&...>(_VSTD::forward<_Args>(__args)...));`. Because `sizeof...(_BoundArgs) == 0`, so apply_functor didn't expand `_args tuple`, all params was ignored.